# Одномерный массив и замена чисел в Java

Tags: java

подскажите как можно сделать одномерный массив 10 чисел , и сделать так что-бы все отрицательные числа были заменены на -1 , и всё это с графическим интерфейсом , я пытаюсь сделать уже всё пересмотрел видео разные просто статьи , никак непойму как задать рандомный генератор на отрицательные числа, так то я вообще нешарю в этом , но простой массив у меня джава выдаёт и неболее

Comment: Отрицательные числа это те же положительные, только отрицательные. Тонкий такой намек.

Comment: вот такая лажа 
import java.util.Random; 

public class javaapplication16 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here   
   int[] a1=new int[10];
   for (int i = 0; i <a1.length ; i++){
    a1[i] = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*100);  
   
   System.out.println(a1 [i]);
    }
    int min = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<a1.length; i++ ) {
        min = a1[i];
        for(int j = 0; j<a1.length; j++) {
            if(min>a1[j])min = a1[j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("min " + min);

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a1=new int[10];
    int maxValue = 100;
    Random rn = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i <a1.length ; i++){
        int newxValue = rn.netInt()%(maxValue+1) - maxValue/2;
        a1[i] = (newxValue < 0)?-1:newxValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое , это явно лучше чем то что у меня получалось )

Answer (score 1):

Не самый оптимальный вариант, но наиболее короткий и наглядный

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream
            .generate(() -> new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) - Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)
            .limit(10)
            .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```